# How to push data to my index using algolia android

Tags: android, algolia

I have a problem pushing data to my index. My code is as follows:

```
Client client = new Client("APP_ID", "SEARCH_ID");

            Index myIndex = client.initIndex("test");
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject()
                        .put("name", "Jimmie")
                        .put("username", "Barninger")
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myIndex.addObjectAsync(jsonObject, null);
```

However nothing happens, and no data is visible in my dashboard. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, can you please show the error that you are getting so that we can better help you?

Comment: Hi, there is no error, it just doesn't push the data objects

Comment: In order to debug, can you replace the 2nd argument `null` with a [CompletionHandler](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-android/blob/1f63db6ebdd3077caa91e74c6553d94e1bcb31d4/algoliasearch/src/main/java/com/algolia/search/saas/CompletionHandler.java) and checkout if you get an error? If so, please copy paste the error in your question

Comment: sorry but didn't understand what you meant

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Thank you for your time I had solved it

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the api keys which previously was `SEARCH_ID`. I changed it to my `ADMIN_API_KEY`:

```
Client client = new Client("APP_ID", "ADMIN_API_KEY");
```

This is because the search-only API key can only be used for searching, while the Admin API key can change, delete or add an object.

The full code is now:

```
Client client = new Client("APP_ID", "ADMIN_API_KEY");

    Index myIndex = client.initIndex("test");

    JSONObject object = null;
    try {
        object = new JSONObject()
                .put("username", "Jimmie")
                .put("name", "Barninger");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   // myIndex.addObjectAsync(object, "myID", null);
    myIndex.addObjectAsync(object, "id", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand more, please replace the `addobjectAsync` line with something like this:

```
index.addObjectAsync(object, new CompletionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void requestCompleted(JSONObject content, AlgoliaException error) {
        if (error != null) {
            // Check what is the error Here
        }
    }
}
```